# Is it possible to convert an EPUB file to HTML?

Tags: conversion, html, epub

There are many questions and answers for reverse direction of converting HTML to EPUB but what about converting an EPUB file to HTML?

There are many tools that can extract CHM (Microsoft Compiled HTML Help) to HTML but I haven't found any tool or method that converts EPUB file to HTML.

Comment: [calibre - About](https://calibre-ebook.com/about)

Comment: The program cannot convert to html, but htmlz. I don't know what htmlz is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [Sigil](https://sigil-ebook.com) (GPLed). While primarily intended as EPUB *editor*, you can also open the EPUB, inspect and *export* the embedded HTML, style and image files.

Comment: Thank you! Well made program.